# copy text from one field to another field

Tags: phpmyadmin, copy

In phpmyadmin table products_description how can I copy the text from the field "products_name" to the field "products_head_title_tag"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as simple as

```
UPDATE products_description SET products_head_title_tag = products_name;
```

Comment: Do you mean the following  INSERT INTO products_description (products_head_title_tag) SELECT products_name FROM products_description; something is strange now I have double the amount of fields I originally had?

Comment: @John Sorry, I updated my answer. You're right, INSERT is not applicable here. A simple update does the trick (at least with my test table here).